# Reduce size of a plot in R notebooks preview

Tags: r, r-markdown, rnotebook

Graphs in Rstudio notebooks generated using "Preview Notebook" take all the width of the HTML page. For example, for the default RStudio notebook:[image]

I  would like the plot to be smaller in the HTML page, not taking all the width.

I tried `fig.width` and `fig.height`, but they do not modify the space that the the plot occupies. For example for `fig.width=1` and `fig.height=1` the output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with the older version of RStudio. After updating RStudio to 1.3.1093, fig.width and fig.height allow you to make the plot smaller.

Comment: Related problem. it worked for me, but yesterday I upgraded to 221.09.01 and now the fig.heigjt does not have any impact on output size below the chunk. Any suggestions how to solve this? Thanks!